# Error when running MICE in R

Tags: r, regression, dataset, missing-data, mice

I have a large dataset with 12 columns that only have weak correlations to each other. I have missing values in 3 of the variables. I studied the distribution of the missing values and conlcude that they are MCAR. What I want to do know is to run a MICE that can impute the missing values. I have run mice before in R once, and it suceeded, but now I am getting the following error:

```
Error in solve.default(xtx + diag(pen)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.35863e-17
```

The code I am running is the following:

```
init=mice(df,maxit=0)
meth=init$method
predM=init$predictorMatrix
predM[,c("Xi","Xj")]=0             #"variables I dont want to use"
meth[c("X1","X2","X3")]='cart'     #"variables that have missing values"
set.seed(1234)
FreqIndimp=mice(df,method=meth,predictorMatrix=predM,m=5)
```

Is it because of the method "cart"?

Comment: You might have nearly perfectly colinear variables or variables on dramatically different scales. Without the actual dataset it's almost impossible to diagnose. Did you try a method other than `cart`?

Comment: No, I did check for correlations. But The problem is fixed. I didn't find out why, but it worked when I coded MICE in a slightly different way.